# completely transparent EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, transparency

i want to transparent an edittext in both Background and textColor sides. so i used this lines in my java code:

```
tempEditText.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
tempEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but unfortunately this tempEditText object shows when i start typing any character on it. i want it to be completely invisible when i typing somthing to it. so i want it to be focused, get some texts, and i want the ability of retrieving strings that typed on it, but all in invisible state of edittext. i test visibility=invisible but in this situation the edittext cant give texts...

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/tempEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#00000000"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

any tips? 
thank you...

Comment: I check your code and its perfectllay worked @ my side . My Main background is white

Comment: so not works in my side! what is the importance of Main BackGround?

Comment: Main background menas main parent view in which edittext is present

Comment: now the background isnt visible, but some TextColor remains and i can see typed texts!

Comment: Can you post that image in which you get text visible in edittext and post xml layout file also ?

Comment: ok. this: http://www.imagetoo.com/images/testmqm.jpg

Comment: Not image url . But upload image here using photo icon near {}.

Comment: stackoverflow alert me: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: then post link of another site . I am not able see photo of link you posted

Comment: http://axgig.com/images/53274380263002128405.jpg

Comment: now show me your xml code for that

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crosswords_tempEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#00000000"
        android:singleLine="true" />

Comment: Please take another xml file and put only edittext in it and check that

Comment: thank you sir, i use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and so sent the edittext everytime below the virtual keyboard and in keyboard.close, set the text of edittext to ""!...

Answer (score 5):

Try:

> android:background="@android:color/transparent"

or

> android:background="@null"

Edit: show the virtual keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(exampleView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: no. not background, but still has a text color! i want "nothing" of my typed characters in visible state...

Comment: This sounds somewhat suspicious, why are you putting an invisible EditText over the top of your activity?

Comment: it is simple brother, for activing android virtual keyboard and doing something with it!

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how to display the virtual keyboard.

Comment: thanks brother but i need an invisible EditText too. bringing the virtual keyboard up is just one of my aims, i so need an exact edittext that is hidden in both background and texts sides.

Answer (score 1):

Change EditText background `android:background="#00000000"` or `android:background="@null"` in your xml file.

For Text Color  `android:textColor="#00000000"` in xml file.

Comment: i set this two in xml, so background removed but characters are so visible with a light color!

Comment: @androidprogrammer2012 i am not able to see that image . Please uploat it here in stack overflow in your question.

Comment: i add url of image to my question body... i cant upload image to stackoverflow. he dont allow me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0">
```

or programmatically you can set alpha to your EditText

```
editText.setAlpha(0.0f);
```

Note: The issue is user will not able to see cursor!

Comment: Explain your answer a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Make the `EditText` background attribute as `#bb000000` for making it transparent.

If you are on Eclipse use the GUI to do it, or do this in your XML file `android:background="#bb000000"`.

[image: IMAGE OF ECLIPSE]]

Comment: when i do your suggest, it hides in Design Mode, but when i run my app, it shows again!

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my XML File :

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/search_input"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/filter"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/search_button"
            />
```

use this line,then it will obviously work

```
 android:background="@null"
```